# Python, Error Accessing to a file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a file downloaded from a python library, not uploaded by me
[File uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Ozi.png)
Im trying to access it using open and read

```
audio_byte = open('/content/audio.mp3', 'r')
audio_open = audio_byte.read()
```

But i got an ffmpeg error

I already tried different open() params, sometimes i got different errors but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Check file path and permissions
• Verify file format and encoding
• Explore alternative methods for reading audio files